# Unable to see hive partitions when running Hudi DeltaStreamer with `TimestampBasedKeyGenerator` (but able to see hudi partitions)

Tags: hive, apache-hudi

In Hudi, I’m using the `TimestampBasedKeyGenerator` partitions (e.g. using the hudi cli I'm able to see partition for `2023-03-05`) in my s3 path (e.g. `s3://my_bucket/my_table/2023-03-25/`):

```
hudi:my_table->show fsview all
╔════════════╤════════════════════════════════════════╤═══════════════════╤═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╤════════════════╤═════════════════╤═══════════════════════╤═════════════╗
║ Partition  │ FileId                                 │ Base-Instant      │ Data-File                                                                                                                                                                                           │ Data-File Size │ Num Delta Files │ Total Delta File Size │ Delta Files ║
╠════════════╪════════════════════════════════════════╪═══════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪═════════════════╪═══════════════════════╪═════════════╣
║ 2023-03-25 │ f5ee270e-ccbb-43e8-9f7e-50d899eb5b91-0 │ 20230412215951850 │ s3://my_bucket/my_table/2023-03-25/f5ee270e-ccbb-43e8-9f7e-50d899eb5b91-0_0-29-237_20230412215951850.parquet │ 434.7 KB       │ 0               │ 0.0 B                 │ []      
...
```

However, when I connect to hive on my AWS EMR setup, I see it should be partitioned:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://ip-my-emr:10000>describe my_table;
...
| updated_at               | bigint     |          |
|                          | NULL       | NULL     |
| # Partition Information  | NULL       | NULL     |
| # col_name               | data_type  | comment  |
| updated_at               | bigint     |          |
```

But when I check hive, I don't see any partitions:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://ip-my-emr:10000>show partitions my_table;
+------------+
| partition  |
+------------+
+------------+
```

I was expecting to see the partitions in hive, like the below (or epochmilliseconds if there is no time conversion):

```
+----------------------+
|      partition       |
+----------------------+
|      2023-03-25      |
|      2023-03-26      |
```

My settings are:

```
hoodie.database.name=my_database
hoodie.table.name=my_table
hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field=id
hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field=updated_at
hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.auto_create_database=true
hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable=true
hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields=__source_ts_ms
hoodie.datasource.write.keygenerator.class=org.apache.hudi.keygen.TimestampBasedKeyGenerator
hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.timestamp.type=EPOCHMILLISECONDS
hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.input.dateformat="run_date=yyyy-MM-dd"
hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.output.dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd
hoodie.deltastreamer.keygen.timebased.timezone=UTC
hoodie.meta.sync.client.tool.class=org.apache.hudi.aws.sync.AwsGlueCatalogSyncTool
```

An example `updated_at` is `1680259659271` and `__source_ts_ms` = `1680259659271`.

Answer (score 0):

My hudi `/etc/hudi/conf/hudi-defaults.conf` settings were incorrect.

The `hoodie.datasource.write.partitionpath.field` should be an epoch in milliseconds (e.g. `1680259659271`), but my `hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_fields` should have been an actual partition date (e.g. `2023-04-01`) instead of another epoch in milliseconds.

I was able to use Kafka Connect's Single Message Transform [TimestampConverter](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/connectors/transforms/timestampconverter.html#timestampconverter) to convert an epoch field into a date string.

Once I fixed these settings, I was able to run the below in hive and see my partitions:

```
show partitions my_table;
```